# Cannot resolve method 'getEarfcn' in 'CellIdentityLte'

Tags: android, android-studio, telephony

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    CellInfo ci = tm.getAllCellInfo().get(0) ; // Registered Cell Tower

if (ci instanceof CellInfoGsm)  {
        ((CellInfoGsm)ci).getCellIdentity().getArfcn();
    } else if (ci instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
        ((CellInfoWcdma)ci).getCellIdentity().getUarfcn();
    } else if (ci instanceof CellInfoLte) {
        ((CellInfoLte)ci).getCellIdentity().getEarfcn();
    }
```

**Errors :**

1. *Cannot resolve method 'getEarfcn' in 'CellIdentityLte'*
2. *Cannot resolve method 'getArfcn' in 'CellIdentityGsm'*
3. *Cannot resolve method 'getUarfcn' in 'CellIdentityWcdma'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved;

setup sdkversion to 24 didn't make attention this was added in API 24.